# Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The directory name is invalid

Tags: github

So this is frustrating me. I'm trying to do a push in github and I am getting this error.
Then it asks for my username and password.  But asked me to create a token.  I have seen how to do this in generating a token to be used as the password, but I do not believe that is solving this particular problem.

Thanks so much for all your help and please let me know if anyone needs more information.

-Chris

[Erro message in command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGhZb.jpg)

[Github screen shot if needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPKM9.jpg)

Comment: Ok so I have been thinking all night what the issue I'm having is.  I know it has to be unique to my own computer system because I've looked everywhere and on youtube and no one seems to be getting the exact message that I am every time I try to "git push -u origin master" for the repository I've created on github.  I believe the folder that I created my app in, foolishly I created in a place my programs don't have administrative access.  Silly me!

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem, but I will post my solution here if someone would possibly have done the same think, but I think it's unlikely.  My problem why I could not push to github was that when I created my Django application I created it in C:/Windows/system32/health_blog.  Administrative permissions were keeping this thing from working, but it works now since I moved my app's folder.